# jquery toggleclass issues not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem with my jquery, I'm looking to collapse my sidebar on click on the hamburger, but toggleclass seeems to be not working.

Ive seen tutorials where toggleclass works just fine, is this a new issue?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: default;
}

body {
  background: white;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;  
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .hamburger {
  width: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  padding: 15px 17px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .hamburger div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 4px;
  background: black;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu {
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu .logo {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu ul {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: grey; 
}

.wrapper .top_navbar .top_menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  left: 10px;
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a span.icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a span.title {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover,
.wrapper .sidebar ul li a.active {
  background: purple;
  color: green;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover:before,
.wrapper .sidebar ul li a.active:before {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .main_container {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.wrapper .main_container .item {
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.wrapper.collapse .sidebar {
  width: 70px;
}

.wrapper.collapse .sidebar ul li a {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper.collapse .sidebar ul li a span.icon {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper.collapse .sidebar ul li a span.title {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper.collapse .main-container {
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
  margin-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5534ba8f0f.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".hamburger").click(function(){
       $(".wrapper").toggleClass(".collapse");
       });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top_navbar">
    <div class="hamburger">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="top_menu">
      <div class="logo">Personal Dashboard</div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">
        <span class="icon">
        <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="title">a</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">
        <span class="icon">
        <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="title">b</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">
        <span class="icon">
        <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="title">c</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">
        <span class="icon">
        <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="title">d</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">
        <span class="icon">
        <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="title">e</span>
      </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="item">
      jgjgjjskg jsgjskljgnrilgn slinglm sir.jmeljfkjsk jfksjekfjsk ejksjfkesjfksefjs kjfjeskfksjfkesjrjskejrkje sjktrskrjske jrrkjskrjekjrsk jrekj
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      jgjgjjskgjsg jskljgnrilgnslinglmsir.jmeljfkjskjfksjekfjskejksjfkesjfksefjskjfjeskfksjfkesjrjskejrkjesjktrskrjskejrrkjskrjekjrskjrekj
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      jgjgjjskg jsgjskljgnrilgn slinglm sir.jmeljfkjsk jfksjekfjsk ejksjfkesjfksefjs kjfjeskfksjfkesjrjskejrkje sjktrskrjske jrrkjskrjekjrsk jrekj
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      jgjgjjskg jsgjskljgnrilgn slinglm sir.jmeljfkjsk jfksjekfjsk ejksjfkesjfksefjs kjfjeskfksjfkesjrjskejrkje sjktrskrjske jrrkjskrjekjrsk jrekj
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take out the `.` in `.collapse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to define `.collapse` as a class because `toggleClass` expects a class.

Try

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".hamburger").click(function(){
       $(".wrapper").toggleClass("collapse");
       });
    });
```